# ExtentReports error on compiling through Maven

Tags: maven

I'm trying to do mvn install from cmd and then i starts compiling the files and then i get the following error which leads to Build failure.

```
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to C:\workspace\tes\target\test-classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/workspace/tes/src/test/java/Test/tes/MyHomepageTestCases/HomeTestCases.java:[17,39] package com.relevantcodes.extentreports does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workspace/tes/src/test/java/Test/tes/MyHomepageTestCases/HomeTestCases.java:[18,39] package com.relevantcodes.extentreports does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workspace/tes/src/test/java/Test/tes/MyHomepageTestCases/HomeTestCases.java:[19,39] package com.relevantcodes.extentreports does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/workspace/tes/src/test/java/Test/tes/MyHomepageTestCases/HomeTestCases.java:[31,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ExtentReports
  location: class Test.tes.MyHomepageTestCases.HomeTestCases
[ERROR] /C:/workspace/tes/src/test/java/Test/tes/MyHomepageTestCases/HomeTestCases.java:[32,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ExtentTest
  location: class Test.tes.MyHomepageTestCases.HomeTestCases
[ERROR] /C:/workspace/tes/src/test/java/Test/tes/MyHomepageTestCases/HomeTestCases.java:[45,28] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ExtentReports
  location: class Test.tes.MyHomepageTestCases.HomeTestCases
[ERROR] /C:/workspace/tes/src/test/java/Test/tes/MyHomepageTestCases/HomeTestCases.java:[47,26] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable LogStatus
  location: class Test.tes.MyHomepageTestCases.HomeTestCases
[INFO] 7 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
```

Below is my code in eclipse where i have already imported the extentreport:

```
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.relevantcodes.extentreports.LogStatus;
import Test.tes.Login.LoginPage;
import Test.tes.MyHomepage.Home;
import Test.tes.Utils.AppUtils;
import Test.tes.Utils.BaseTestSetup;

public class HomeTestCases extends BaseTestSetup {      //use of inheritance

    private static Logger log=Logger.getLogger(HomeTestCases.class);
    private LoginPage lpobj = null;
    private Home homeObj = null;

    ExtentReports extent;
    ExtentTest test;
```

Comment: So do you have a dependency on `extentreports` in your POM? Can you post it?

Comment: No i have added the jar file in Java Build Path and not in POM

Comment: There's your problem. In a Maven project, dependencies are added to the POM. The IDE integration with Maven will take care of adding it to the classpath inside of your IDE. But Maven and the IDE are different tools.

Comment: Thanks Tunaki it worked after adding it into the pom